# How to omit first column in stringr pattern replacement?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataframe with a column for each of the 12 months as shown in the data below. I am using `str_replace` to append some new endings to each of the column names. In my actual dataset, I have 13 columns where the first column is a type of id column, followed by 12 columns -- one for each of the months. How would I apply the `str_replace` function so that I omit the first id column in the pattern? Thank you in advance!

```
library(stringr)

# Fake data
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 12, nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- paste(month.abb, 20:31, 4:15, sep = "_")

# Replacement
names(df) <- str_replace(names(df),
                         "\\d+$",
                         rep(c("winter", "spring", "summer", "autumn"), each = 3))

df
```

Comment: try `names(df)[-1]` (in both places)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying `names(df[-1])` on accident instead.